# jQuery slideToggle function slids a div down then immediately back up

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a very simple slide toggle function as below.

```
$(".quickLinksLink").click(function () {
    $(".quickLInksList").slideToggle(100);  
});
```

It works but it slides the quickLInksList div down and then immediately back up. Sort of like peeka boo effect. this happen everywhere where a slideToggle function is used.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: there is something you're not showing us. Your question only makes sense if you're double-clicking the link.

Comment: code has typos; case matters. (it is not the cause here, but it's important to note that we can only debug what you give us.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/fznGg/ <- Code's working here. There's something else going on.

Comment: after making this post, I looked at this page source and realized that the .js file that contains the functions was being loaded twice. I corrected this and it works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle with the slideToggle method implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/R2Q86/

In my example there is a button that calls the method for a div. How do you want to fire the method?